# To create an output texture do I need a call to texImage2D?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

In Webgl, I currently make the following calls to create a texture whether it is used for input or for output. Do I really need the call to texImage2D knowing that my shader will be overwriting the values in the texture?

```
const texture = gl.createTexture();
// Bind the texture so the following methods effect this texture.
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,  // Level of detail.
    this.encoder.internalFormat, width, height,
    0,  // Always 0 in OpenGL ES.
    this.encoder.format, this.encoder.channelType, null);
this.checkError();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
return texture as WebGLTexture;
```

Comment: It looks like I do need that. I just skipped that and ran my code. Then i got FRAME_BUFFER_INCOMPLETE status errors.

Comment: How else would webgl know what size and format to make the texture? It's that or `copyTexImage2D` or  in WebGL2 `texStorage2D`

Comment: Thanks gman. absolutely. I completely ignored those parameters

Comment: Also, since WebGL is often translated into DirectX (i.e. Chrome), a texture might not exist at all (as far as underlying API is concerned) until `texImage2D` is called, since DX needs all these parameters to create the texture.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @riv

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete code sample which will create a texture equal to canvas size (this could be used for offscreen rendering)

```
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();

const texture = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
```

You can later use rendered texture, or read it contents with `gl.readPixels`

Comment: Thank you. I have the code already. My question was something else.